# Write file in Azure App Service using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to create file in App_Data dir of MVC app while its running on Azure- App Service (Not Virtual Machine)?

Actually I have to download images from URL and save to the App_Data folder for further processing. I am able to do this in development laptop. I get the path of my App_Data folder using the below line and save files there:-

```
 String localFileName = Server.MapPath("..\\App_Data") + "\\" + saveFileName;
```

I am not sure it is possible in the Azure's App Service.
What can be alternative way of doing it?
Please help.

Comment: Have you explored these options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction

Comment: It is possible, but it is not a good practice. You want to look at Blob Storage or File Storage.